# Select distinct columns where another column does not contain a particular value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

| id | name | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | A |
| 2 | foo | C |
| 3 | bar | A |
| 4 | bar | D |

I want to select all names where **col1** has no entry **D**

The result should be "**foo**"

I tried

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table WHERE col1 != D
```

But it returns "**foo**" and "**bar**" because of id 3

Comment: Shouldnt that be `col1 != "D"`

Comment: Whoever voted to move this to https://dba.stackexchange.com... this question has absolutely nothing to do with database administration

Comment: Good call, [its still basic SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so here it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid the over use of `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(col1='D') = 0
```

As an aggregate over names is needed `GROUP BY name`. `HAVING` applies after the aggregation. `col1='D'` is a 1/0 expression so summing them up and you want 0 to be the total.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id   INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  ,col1 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(id,name,col1) VALUES 
(1,'foo','A'),
(2,'foo','C'),
(3,'bar','A'),
(4,'bar','D');
```

use `Group_Concat()` as follows

```
select
name
/*,Group_Concat(col1)  col1 */
from mytable 
group by name
HAVING Group_Concat(col1) not like '%D%'
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dnQK9Vej)